# Frames inside Tabcontrol always refreshes when clicking on Different Tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I implemented Dynamic Tab creation in WPF using MVVM pattern. Inside each Tab is a Frame and the frame is hosting a Page.

```
<TabControl Name="mainTabControl" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableCollectionTabContent}" >
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <!--this is the body of the TabItem template-->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame  NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
                    Source="{Binding FrameSource}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

My ViewModel looks like this.

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        private TabContent tabContent;
        public ObservableCollection<TabContent> ObservableCollectionTabContent { get; set; }
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {

            ObservableCollectionTabContent = new ObservableCollection<TabContent>();
        }



        public void NewTab(String header, String navigatePageUri)
        {

            tabContent = new TabContent { Header = header, FrameSource = navigatePageUri };

            this.ObservableCollectionTabContent.Add(tabContent);

            // Set the new tab to be the current tab
            ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ObservableCollectionTabContent);
            if (collectionView != null)
            {
                collectionView.MoveCurrentToNext();

            }

        }

    }

      public sealed class TabContent
    {
            public String Header { get; set; }
            public String FrameSource { get; set; }

    }
```

Now my problem is when more than 1 tabs is open and want to switch between Tabs the frame inside is automatically refreshed, hence creating new instances of pages hosted inside, which I don't want. Any idea why it might me happening?

Comment: There is no `PropertyChanged` event in `FrameSource` property, so how it can be seen that Frame is always updated when you click on `Tabs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabControl ALLWAYS re-instatiates the contents of Tabs when they come into view. This is by design.
If you want each of the Tabs to retain state when they are no longer selected, then you need to implement your own custom Tabs.

If you google this issue, you will see plenty of examples of people writing their own statefull tab controls